# Can't display a image from sqlite db on a ios app

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiimage, nsdata

Im working on a iOS app, so i need to save a image that the user will choose from his album or will take it from the camera. Im doing this with a picker

Then i try to save the image into the table with this code:

```
- (IBAction)saveUOme:(id)sender
{
    NSString * _name = name.text;
    NSString * _lastname = lastname.text;
    NSString * _email = email.text;
    NSString * _workemail = workEmail.text;
    NSString * _cellphone = cell.text;
    NSString * _phone = homePhone.text;
    NSString * _money = amount.text;
    NSString * _stuff = stuff.text;
    NSString * _cause = cause.text;
    //NSData *_image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSData *_image = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString * _date = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];

    if (!switchR.on)
    {
        _date=@"";
    }
    //NSString *_error;


    NSLog(@" %@ ,%@ ,%@ ,%@ ,%@ ,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@ ", _name,_lastname,_email,_workemail,_cellphone,_phone,_money,_stuff,_cause,_date);


    if(([_name length]!=0 && [_lastname length] !=0 && [_money length] !=0) || ([_name length]!=0 && [_lastname length] !=0 && [_stuff length] !=0 ) )
    {

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO addUOmeTable ('name','lastname','email','workemail','cellphone','phone','money','stuff','cause','date','image') VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@');", _name, _lastname, _email, _workemail, _cellphone, _phone,_money,_stuff,_cause,_date,_image];

        char *err;

        if (sqlite3_exec(_db, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_close(_db);
            NSAssert(0,@"No se pudo agregar");
        }else
        {

            NSLog(@"Se agregaron los datos");

        }


    }else
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Data is Missing"
                                                        message:@"Name, Lastname or Amount/Stuff"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        /*
        FirstViewController *obj =[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:obj.view];*/
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];



    }



}
```

So far i think this works because in the database i get this as save object

```
<89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 00000400 00000300 08020000 0035d882 5a000000 1c69444f 54000000 02000000 00000001 80000000 28000001 80000001 80000c6c fd9ea091 34000040 00494441 5478019c 7df7775c 45b6357f ce7b3360 a5ce4959 b2255956 ce9d734e ea56ce96 73c0186c c0806d8c 73ced9c6 e4641be7 086f6698 21e300cc fbf9dbb7 4feb50be 2d9b79df 5a67d5da 75ead4a9 bab7c33d fb567a2e 38520e09 0f574222 4395e1c1 8ae84065 46aac37d 95c1de4a 7fa2dc93 2873c74b 9db1325b acbc275c da1d2eef 8c967644 4ada22a6 d6b0be29 ac6b8ea8 5b23eaf6 88aa3ba6 b624d4ce 84d693d2 85fb0df1 2153efa0 2135a84b 0de953a.....>
```

Then i try to select all from the database with this code

```
-(void) selectData
{
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM addUOmeTable ORDER BY name ASC"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, Nil)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            char *id1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *id_uomeDoubt = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:id1];

            char *name1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:name1];


            char *lastname1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            NSString *lastname = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:lastname1];

            char *email1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
            NSString *email = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:email1];

            char *workemail1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
            NSString *workemail = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:workemail1];

            char *cellphone1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
            NSString *cellphone = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cellphone1];

            char *phone1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
            NSString *phone = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:phone1];

            char *money1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7);
            NSString *money = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:money1];

            char *staff1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
            NSString *staff = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:staff1];

            char *couse1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9);
            NSString *couse = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:couse1];

            char *date1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10);
            NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date1];

            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 11) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 11)];


            doubtArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:id_uomeDoubt,name,lastname,email,workemail,cellphone,phone,money,staff,couse,date,data, nil];


            [uomeDoubts addObject:doubtArr];


        }
    }

    [self.myTable reloadData];

}
```

And finally i try to display the image into a cell using this code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell= [[CustomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }


    NSArray *debtor = [uomeDoubts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSString *nombre = [debtor objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *nombre2 = [debtor objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *apellido = [debtor objectAtIndex:2];
    nombre = [nombre stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    nombre = [nombre stringByAppendingString:[debtor objectAtIndex:2]];

    cell.TitleLable.text = nombre;

    NSString *tempo = [debtor objectAtIndex:7] ;


    if ([tempo length] ==0)
    {
        NSString *st = @"Stuff - ";
        st = [st stringByAppendingString:[debtor objectAtIndex:8]];

        cell.SubtitleLable.text = st;

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *mny = @"Money - $";
        mny = [mny stringByAppendingString:[debtor objectAtIndex:7]];

        cell.SubtitleLable.text = mny;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ %@",nombre2,apellido);


    NSData* data = [debtor objectAtIndex:11];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];




    return cell;

}
```

And i dont get any error , the only thing is that the image is not display at all

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Let me ask you this. :) Suppose you just fetch a `debtor` from `uomeDoubts` and try to show his object at index 11 as a UIImage in a UIImageView somewhere else in your interface (not as part of a table). Does that work?

Comment: If not, suppose you just fetch the data right out of the database with your `NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 11) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 11)];` and immediately try to show _that_ as a UIImage in a UIImageView somewhere else in your interface. Does _that_ work?

Comment: In other words, try to track down the exact point in your chain where things are going wrong. Now you can shorten your question and ask just about the thing where the problem really is.